# bootstrap 3 full width image and div in container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set some divs to `width: 100%` on Twitter Bootstrap 3 (including no paddings or margins).

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rq9ycjcx/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">Menu</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gray">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="breadcrumbs">Main page > page </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </header>

    <footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row dark">
        <div class="col-md-3">Footer 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Footer 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Footer 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">Footer 4</div>
    </div>
    </footer>    
</div>
```

1. What is the right way to get image `http://placehold.it/350x150` `width: 100%`, including no paddings or margins?
2. Page title and breadcrumbs height is `80px`.
   If I resize window to smaller screen (e.g. mobile), text `Main page > page` disappears (it's somewhere but not on own row). 
   How to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested above, you can create a helper class

```
.padding-0 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

and apply it to any HTML elements for which you need a padding reset. So in your case, it would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 padding-0">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>    
</div>
```

For the second problem, set `height` of `.gray` class to `auto` :

```
@media () {
    .gray {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You could also remove `line-height: 80px`, it's optional :)

http://jsfiddle.net/rq9ycjcx/8/

Comment: Second problem is not solved :( I need that `page title` and `breadcrumbs` stack vertically one by one if small screen. But I don't know how to deal with `height` on bigger screen. Should I use `media queries` to remove `height` on small screens?

Comment: I modified my most, sorry I misunderstood, thought you want them one beside another.

Answer (score 10):

Use `<div class="container-fluid">`.  As per Bootstrap Docs: **Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.**

There is 0 padding on `container-fluid`.

In your code you have what appears to be `body` content in your `header` and you also have a `div class="container"` outside of your `header` and `footer`.  This is not correct, you should have your `container/container-fluid` inside of your body.  Also for your header you should use `<nav="nav navbar-nav">`.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9ycjcx/6/)**

Comment: You are just mixing everything. The requester tries to size an image in a column, there is nothing to deal with the container size.

Concerning the header tag, refering to w3schools : 
- The <header> element specifies a header for a document or section.
- The <header> element should be used as a container for introductory content.
- You can have *several* <header> elements *in one* document.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" way to do that in Bootstrap 3. It means you have to reset padding for the exact column.
You can create a class such as this one:

```
.col-md-12.resetPadding { padding:0px }
```

About `Main page > page` disappearing, I don't see this problem on my browsers (tested on Chrome and FF), but you have `line-height: 80px` there and as you said your breadcrumbs div has `height: 80px;`, so try to reduce `line-height` property and see how it works.

Comment: I think it wont work until u do that .col-md-12.resetPadding { padding:0px !important }

Comment: No, bootstrap don't use !important there. So you can overwrite it easly using {padding:0px}.

Comment: there is a "right" way to do it, it's by using `container-fluid` instead of `container`

Comment: `container-fluid` still has paddings he need to reset.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to remove the `<div class="col-md-12">...</div>` and add your content directly inside the row tag. The row tag removes the left & right gutters, whereas the cold-md-12 essentially adds the gutters back in.

The Bootstrap 3 documentation says that for single full width items you don't need any markup, eg just wrap it in `<p>` tags. However this will show the 15px gutters due to the page markup. So by simply adding in the `row` tag and placing your content directly inside this you will get 100% width content and be compliant with the BS3 documentation.